# Integrate $(cos(\theta)+D)^m$ (power of cosine plus constant)

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I am trying to [make the Blinn-Phong BRDF conserve energy exactly](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/energy-conservation-for-blinn-phong-brdf). During the course of this, I have reduced part of the problem to the following integral ($D$ and $m<0$ are constants w.r.t. the variable of integration):$$
I = \int_0^{2 \pi} (cos(\theta)+D)^m d \theta
$$This turns out to be a surprisingly difficult integral.  WolframAlpha, for example, [gives a mess](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28cos%28theta%29+%2B+D%29%5Em+d+theta) for the indefinite integral, and doesn't even output anything for the definite integral.

How can I solve this?

**Please note**: as above, $m<0$.  Also, while ideally $m$ is a real number, making $m$ an integer is an acceptable restriction.

Comment: Ooops, you should have mentioned that before I write my answer! :D

Comment: @H.R. I assume you mean the part about $m<0$. This was in the question 15 minutes before your answer appeared, but I did edit afterward to make it more prominent. :D

Comment: You can check my new answer now.

Comment: @H.R. Unfortunately, $|m|$ can be up to $\approx 10^5$, $\approx 10^6$, so doing a brute force partial fraction expansion isn't really practical. I've been trying different approaches myself before I decide what to do. Have a +1 for your work so far, though.

Comment: I will think through other methods and let you know if any comes to mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my calculations, I replaced $m$ by $\alpha $ since it is more like a real number! We have these assumptions only

$$\begin{align}
  & D,\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \\ 
 & D>1 \\ 
\end{align}$$

First of all you can simplify your integral a little

$$\eqalign{
  & I = \int_0^{2\pi } {{{\left( {\cos \theta  + D} \right)}^\alpha }d\theta }  = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{\left( {\cos \theta  + D} \right)}^\alpha }d\theta }   \cr 
  & \,\,\, = 2\int_0^\pi  {{{\left( {\cos \theta  + D} \right)}^\alpha }d\theta }  = 2{D^\alpha }\int_0^\pi  {{{\left( {1 + {{\cos \theta } \over D}} \right)}^\alpha }d\theta }  \cr}\tag{1} $$

Now I make use of the binomial **series**

$$\begin{array}{l}
{\left( {1 + x} \right)^\alpha } = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\alpha \\
n
\end{array}} \right)} {x^n}\,\,\,\text{which uniformly converges when}\,\,\,\,\left| x \right| < 1\\
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\alpha \\
n
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{{\prod\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\alpha  - i} \right)} }}{{n!}} = \frac{{\alpha \left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)...\left( {\alpha  - n + 1} \right)}}{{n!}}
\end{array}\tag{2}$$

considering this we can write

$${\left( {1 + \frac{{\cos \theta }}{D}} \right)^\alpha } = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\alpha \\
n
\end{array}} \right)} {\left( {\frac{{\cos \theta }}{D}} \right)^n}\tag{3}$$

but (3) converges **uniformly** for **all** $\theta $ since $D>1$ and hence the condition for uniform convergence $\left| {\frac{{\cos \theta }}{D}} \right| < 1$ is satisfied identically. **Uniform convergence** of (3) let us to integrate it **term by term**. Accordingly, we can write

$$I = 2{D^\alpha }\int_0^\pi  {\left[ {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\alpha \\
n
\end{array}} \right){{\left( {\frac{{\cos \theta }}{D}} \right)}^n}} } \right]d\theta }  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\alpha \\
n
\end{array}} \right){D^{\alpha  - n}}\left( {\int_0^\pi  {{{\cos }^n}\theta d\theta } } \right)} \right]}\tag{4}$$

Again I repeat that interchanging summation and integration in (4) holds due to the uniform convergence of the binomial series. I just leave the computation of ${\int_0^\pi  {{{\cos }^n}\theta d\theta } }$ for you which is not a hard task to carry out. I think it is the best you can obtain for this!

Cheers! :)

Comment: I think partial fractions here are more complicated than you think. Also, this substitution is problematic because it integrates over two discontinuities in $tan$. Try subbing the limits of integration, for example.

Comment: You are right! :)

Comment: Is the constant $D$ restricted in any ways? :) I am trying to figure another strategy of solution.

Comment: $D:=(\cos(a)\cos(p)+1)/(\sin(p)\sin(a))$, where $0<a,p<\pi/2$. Therefore, $D$ must be a positive real number.

Comment: and also **greater than one**! right? I think I am close to find some closed form  solution.

Comment: Huh yeah, I guess you're right $D>1$. :) Be ye warned, I've thought I was close on this problem several times before too. But 9 pages of work and I still don't have it, so . . .

Comment: See the new answer. :)

Comment: What is your idea about the new answer? :)

Comment: I'll take it, since it's better than what Mathematica produces (and contrastingly I know how this one works). The cosine integral isn't really easy, though. N.B. I have [posted](http://geometrian.com/programming/tutorials/energyblinn/index.php) a bounty (real money!) for a fully closed-form solution. Perhaps considering it in the context of the original problem makes it easier.

Comment: You can find cosine integral in books like **Mathematical Hand Book of Formulas and Tables** by Spiegel. Good Luck! :)
Let me know if any other things appeared as the solution. :)