# Computing the $n_{th}$ Derivative of $f(x)^m$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition

I know that there is a general formula to compute the $n_{th}$ derivative of a composition as it is mentioned in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503696/how-to-compute-the-n-th-derivative-of-a-composition-left-f-circ-g-r). The formula is named **Faà di Bruno's formula**. However, it is really ugly and complicated! :)

Now, I want to find the $n_{th}$ derivative of $f(x)^m$ where $m$ is some positive integer. So, I am interested in

$${\left( {f{{(x)}^m}} \right)^{(n)}} \equiv f{(x)^{\left( {m,n} \right)}} = ?$$

Is there a **tidy** formula for this?

---

**My Computations**

$$\matrix{
   {f{{(x)}^{\left( {m,1} \right)}} = } \hfill & {{{m!} \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - 1,0} \right)}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,1} \right)}}} \hfill & {} \hfill & {} \hfill & {} \hfill  \cr 
   {f{{(x)}^{\left( {m,2} \right)}} = } \hfill & {{{m!} \over {\left( {m - 2} \right)!}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - 2,0} \right)}}{{\left( {f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,1} \right)}}} \right)}^2}} \hfill &  +  \hfill & {{{m!} \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - 1,0} \right)}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,2} \right)}}} \hfill & {} \hfill  \cr 
   {f{{(x)}^{\left( {m,3} \right)}} = } \hfill & {{{m!} \over {\left( {m - 3} \right)!}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - 3,0} \right)}}{{\left( {f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,1} \right)}}} \right)}^3}} \hfill &  +  \hfill & {{{m!} \over {\left( {m - 2} \right)!}}{{3!} \over {2!}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - 2,0} \right)}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,2} \right)}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,1} \right)}}} \hfill &  +  \hfill  \cr 
   {\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + } \hfill & {{{m!} \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)!}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - 1,0} \right)}}f{{(x)}^{\left( {1,3} \right)}}} \hfill & {} \hfill & {} \hfill & {} \hfill  \cr 
   . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill  \cr 
   . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill  \cr 
   . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill & . \hfill  \cr 
 } $$

It should be something like

$$f{(x)^{\left( {m,n} \right)}} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{C_i}(n,x)f{{(x)}^{\left( {m - i,0} \right)}}} $$

however, determining ${{C_i}(n,x)}$ is not easy as it seems! :)

Comment: Can you write the first few iterations? This might help.